# Нужна программа в excel для облегчения рутинной работы

Tags: excel, visual-basic, таблицы

Суть в том, что в листы под названием "БЛА-1", "БЛА-2", "БЛА-3" и "БЛА-4" будут вноситься данные о полетах с указанием даты полета, количества управлений, времени налета и фамилией оператора. Надо чтобы программа вычисляла полеты конкретного оператора (причем оператор может летать на любом из БЛА) и вносила всё вышеперечисленное в лист с его фамилией. Прикрепляю скрины, там, для примера, вбито вручную как должно быть
Главные вопросы: Как это можно реализовать, в каком направлении мыслить?

[image: Исходная таблица "БЛА-1"]

[image: Другой лист этого же файла, с данными полетов конкретного оператора]

Comment: Дружище, вопрос нормально не сформулировал, сорян. Меня интересует в каком направлении вообще двигать? Как вариант я рассматривал написать все через формулы как в 5-7 классах нас учили(в любом случае даже в этом нужна помощь), потом на киберфоруме увидел, что типы писали код на Basic, поэтому отправился сюда за ответами. В общем если можешь хотя бы дать толчок в нужном направлении, было бы неплохо

Comment: Да наверняка можно экселевскими формулами сделать, без бейсиков.

Comment: используйте фильтры, попробуйте перевести и понять, может и по картинкам поймёте - суть - перенести только данные. соотвествующие поисковой маске, в вашем случае - фамилия пилота. https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/excel-filter-add-use-remove/  и на русском https://exceltable.com/filtr-sortirovka/filtraciya-dannyh-v-excel

Comment: https://ru.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/4585-excel-advanced-filter-to-another-sheet.html Как скопировать данные на другой лист с помощью расширенного фильтра в Excel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Почитал ваш коммент, оставлю просто на заметку.

Использовать можно любой язык программирования, байсик есть внутри самого MS-Excel, поэтому бухгалтера зачастую используют именно его.

Опытные инженеры предпочитаю свой любимый инженерный язык Python, он простой и понятный используют в основном библиотеку openpyxl.

Вэб разработчики предпочитают PHP с его phpspreadsheet - библиотека мощная как швейцарский нож.

Те кто пишут оконные преложения предпочитают C# EPPlus, Delphi/C++ используют нативные ActiveX от Microsoft.

Вас какое из направлений интересует? Могу дополнить ответ подробнее о любой из них.

Совсем новичку я бы советовал ознакомиться именно с Python. Он очень простой и понятный.

Comment: "любимый инженерный язык Python" - это спорное заявление :-). А я бы посоветовал новичку начать с формул в Excel и VBA.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, это задачка просто нужна была для упрощения работы, углубленно этим заниматься никто не собирается, тем более это даже не мне надо было, а так Пайтон как новичок пока изучаю)